# connect pad inside component symbol

Tags: eaglecad, pad, connect

I'm trying to connect  A4 to pin 5 in 6050 in the picture.

[image: a4 to 5]

When I click those with the net tool, it also connects A2, which is not what I need. If I use the delete tool and erase the junction, they are still connected. How can I just connect a4 to 5?

Comment: What a horrible component symbol. Drawing wires over components is never a good idea and makes for a very ugly schematic.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: I would say you do it by fixing that component to not have connections inside the symbol. They should all be on the outside.

Comment: Hi, this is eagle pcb by autodesk. Library is user contributed. I'm just figuring my way into electronics in general and found it, but had plenty of problems trying to connect. Will find how to edit symbol then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend not to put a pin *inside* a component symbol, it will make the schematic unclear.
You can differentate between the component's pins by grouping them and spacing them, to increase readability.
E.g grouping all VCC pins at the top of the component symbol and GND pins at the bottom, skip a pin between below A0 and above A5, as shown below.

[image]

PS. I just edited OP's picture here and assumed a GND1 and GND2. It's not meant to be a correct implementation of OP's case, rather as illustration of grouping and spacing pins.

Comment: Thanks, will find how to edit symbols so I can use it, similar as you proposed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is connected to A2 is because you have A4 within the body of the part and go over A2.

As per KiCAD Library Convention

https://klc.kicad.org/symbol/s3/s3.5/

**Pin connection points must be placed outside of the symbol**

This isn't to work around limitations, this is for consistency and equally you have taken the trace to A2